# Different fill-column for comments than code in programming modes

Tags: fill-column

I don't mind if the occasional code line runs long.  For example, the Shopify ruby standard allows lines of 120.  But I want comments to be restricted to the first 78 lines or so.  Is there any way in a programming major mode to have a different fill column for comment lines than for code line?

Comment: Not that I know of. But it's easy to just `C-x f` to change the fill-column here or there. Then `M-q` to re-fill.

Comment: What are `fill-paragraph-function` and `fill-forward-paragraph-function` set to? Emacs actually has some logic for filling comments differently than the code, but it may not be relevant in your case, if `ruby-mode` overrides the default behavior (which it probably does). Anyways, my approach would be to look for `ruby-mode`'s function to fill paragraph, and see if it is possible to extend / replace it with something of your own design that deals with comments the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  With some prodding from @wvxvw, I looked at some source code, though the code for `fill-paragraph` rather than `ruby-mode`.  There is a function for filling comments, but it does not take a `fill-column` parameter.  So, I tried the following advice, which appears to do the trick:

```
  (defvar ded:fill-column-for-progs 78)

  (defun ded:prog-fill-paragraph (orig-fun &rest args)
    (let ((fill-column ded:fill-column-for-progs))
      (apply orig-fun args)))

  (advice-add 'fill-comment-paragraph :around #'ded:prog-fill-paragraph)
```

The `ded:` is just my personal prefix.  So far, so good.  It even uses justification when used with the universal argument.